# How to enable Maxlinear PHY GPY115 Drivers

Tags: drivers, server, ethernet, 22.04, nic

About a [year ago](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/7d901a1e878a1cf8dd3ba7b4c057ad5eb7a40af0) driver support for Maxlinear GPY115 NIC was merged into kernel v5.15-rc1. I hoped this driver would work on a new system I'm working on (Onlogic HX310). I installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS but I can't seem to get them to work (eg. get an IP-address and access internet). Do I need to install or enable something to make them functional or are they simply not yet supported? Any help would be appreciated.

**Linux bootup output:**

During network configuration the following warning pops-up:

```
UBSAN: shift-out-of-bounds in 
/build/linux-WLUive/linux-5.15.0/drivers/net/ethernet/stmicro/stmmac/dwmac4_core.c:224:12
Shift exponent 40 is too large for 32-bit type 'unsigned int'
```

Then I get the following error:

`Maxlinear Ethernet GPY115B stmmac-3:01: gpy_config_aneg failed -110`

**Config information**

Result of *grep MAXLINEAR_GPHY /boot/config-5.15.0-40-generic*:

```
CONFIG_MAXLINEAR_GPHY=m
```

The mxl-gpy.ko module is present in:

```
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/mxl-gpy.ko
```

I have also executed: sudo modprobe mxl-gpy, but no difference

chili555: dmesg doesn't return anything about mxl, the previously mentioned error does come up with phy as argument.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is supported, but I might not have your exact kernel (my more recent ones are custom compiled, using the Ubuntu kernel  configuration). Check for it in the kernel configuration: `grep MAXLINEAR_GPHY /boot/config-5.15.0-stock` (change the file name for your kernel). And check that the module is actually present: `/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-stock/kernel/drivers/net/phy/mxl-gpy.ko`. If the module is not being loaded somehow automatically, try `sudo modprobe mxl-gpy`.

Comment: Plaese edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep -i mxl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? I'm having the same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem.  OnLogic recently has enabled support for Ubuntu 22.04 but older units need a firmware update to the GPY115.  You'll need to send it in.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your system is detecting that it needs the MAXLINEAR_GPHY GPY115 driver and it is trying to start, but is failing.

It appears to be a bug between the subroutine "gpy_config_aneg", within `drivers/net/phy/mxl-gpy.c` and `drivers/net/ethernet/stmicro/stmmac/dwmac4_core.c`. There have not been any recent functional changes to either's code since kernel 5.15, so trying a newer kernel is unlikely to help (but I suggest to try anyhow, just as a test).

I also could not find any related already existing bug reports (but didn't try very hard).

Comment: Hi Doug, I have tried Fedora Server 36 (running kernel 5.17) to see it makes a difference but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The bugzilla link was forwarded to netdev@vger.kernel.org, you can read some basic analysis of the problem and hopefully the right people have been copied:

https://lore.kernel.org/netdev/b6b4e138-8a12-c80f-0cd3-1681605ac6ac@gmail.com/